# Recursive Regular Expression for mod rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to recursivly modify my web page urls, but am not able to figure out rewrite rule for this situation:

I want to change my URLs from pattern

```
http://mywebsite.com/token1-token2-token3-token4-categoryname
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/?cat=categoryname&search=token1+token2+token3+token4
```

Challenge is that the number of tokens in url may vary, so I need to somehow handle token matching and conversion recursively. Any ideas how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# Remove all of the - and replace with +
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ /$1+$2 [L]

# only rewrite when there are no more -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\-
RewriteRule ^(.+)\+([^\+]+)$ /?cat=$2&search=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This too won't work because there is no limit on number of tokens, first rule works only when there are exactly two tokens

Comment: @scientist.rahul No, mod_rewrite loops. The first rule will continue to work until there are no more "-"'s. Mod_rewrite re-applies all the rules until the URI going into the rewrite engine is the same as the URI coming out. Since a `-` is replaced with `+`, the URI's are different and mod_rewrite will apply all the rules again to the new URI.

Comment: @scientist.rahul You can see how this works in the rewrite log of a test I ran using those exact rules: http://pastebin.com/NsjK0c5X

Comment: Thanks a lot it actually works, I was not aware that mod-rewrite redirects, you log was really helpful, thanks for the help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule  ^/?(.+)\-([^\-]+)$  /?cat=$2&search=$1  [QSA,L]`

Comment: Omega, thanks for answering, but it won't work since I need to replace the '-' between tokens by '+' too